# How to use Set-ItemProperty to set EnabledProtocols for each Application associated with IIS WebSite?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The following powershell successfully updates the EnabledProtocols property for my WebSite "Test Services"

```
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\sites\Test Services' -name EnabledProtocols -Value 
"http,net.tcp,net.pipe"
```

Are there any Powershell gurus here who know the syntax for setting the EnabledProtocols property for each WebApplication associated with the WebSite "Test Services"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find applications under a site using a where `$_.Schema.Name -eq "Application"`. Then for each application using the `Set-ItemProperty`, set `enabledProtocols` property value.

**Example**

You should run the following script as administrator:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration -Force
Get-ChildItem "IIS:\sites\test" |
    Where-Object {$_.Schema.Name -eq "Application"} | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        Set-ItemProperty $_.PSPath `
        -name enabledProtocols -Value "http,net.tcp,net.pipe"}
```

**Important Notes**

- The script should be run as administrator.
- Pay attention to character case of the property name.
- Also make sure `WebAdministration` module is imported.)
  Also pay attention to the `enabledProtocols` name, with camel case syntax.

Comment: Hi Reza I need to loop though all Web applications associated with a Website and set EnabledProtocols. It's the looping through each WebApplication I am not sure how to do.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The solution is tested and works properly, let me know if you have any question about the answer.